# expecting <"edit"> but rendering with <[]>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

Hi everyone I'm testing my app controllers and I have a problem. I have tests for update action which fails:

```
describe "PUT #update" do 
    before :each do 
      @car_service = create(:car_service)
    end

    it "locates the requested @message" do 
      put :update, id: @car_service, car_addition: attributes_for(:car_service)
      assigns(:car_addition).should eq(@car_service)
    end

    context "valid attributes" do 
      it "changes @car_service's attributes" do 
        put :update, id: @car_service, car_addition: attributes_for(:car_service, name: "Test")
        @car_service.reload
        @car_service.name.should eq("Test")
      end

      it "redirects to the updated message" do 
        put :update, id: @car_service, car_addition: attributes_for(:car_service)
        should redirect_to admin_car_additions_url
      end
    end

    context "invalid attributes" do 
      it "does not change @car_addition's attributes" do 
        put :update, id: @car_service, car_addition: attributes_for(:car_service, name: nil)
        @car_service.reload
        @car_service.name.should_not be_nil
      end

      it "re-renders the edit method" do 
        put :update, id: @car_service, car_addition: attributes_for(:car_addition)

        should render_template :edit

      end
    end
  end
```

when i run this tests only one test not pass("re-renders the edit method") and throw out following error:

```
Failure/Error: should render_template('edit')
       expecting <"edit"> but rendering with <[]>
     # ./spec/controllers/admin/car_additions_controller_spec.rb:100:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>
```

My controller looks like this:

```
module Admin
  class CarAdditionsController < ApplicationController
    include Admin::BaseController

    load_and_authorize_resource

    add_breadcrumb I18n.t('car_additions.car_addition.home'), :admin_root_path
    add_breadcrumb I18n.t('car_additions.car_additions'), :admin_car_additions_path

    def index
    end

    def new
      add_breadcrumb t('car_additions.car_addition.new')
    end

    def edit
      add_breadcrumb t('car_additions.car_addition.edit')
    end

    def create
      if @car_addition.save
        flash[:notice] = t("car_additions.created")
        redirect_to action: :index
      else
        add_breadcrumb t('car_additions.car_addition.new')
        render :new
      end
    end

    def update
      if @car_addition.update(car_addition_params)
        flash[:notice] = t("car_additions.updated")
        redirect_to action: :index
      else
        render :edit
      end
    end

    def destroy
      @car_additon.destroy
      flash[:error] = t("car_additions.destroy")
      redirect_to action: :index
    end

    private
    def car_addition_params
      params.require(:car_addition).permit(:name, :type, :image,
        :image_cache, :remove_image)
    end
  end
end
```

I'm using devise and CanCan for authorization. Please help.

---

I'm pass `attributes_for(:car_addition)` because this is not valid attributes. When I changed this to:
 `attributes_for(:car_addition, name: nil)` it's still not working...

Comment: Why do you pass `attributes_for(:car_addition)` instead of `attributes_for(:car_addition, name: nil)`? Are you sure the params are invalid?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `render_views` method in order to have your views rendered in specs:

```
describe "PUT #update" do
  render_views
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @MateuszUrbański are you sure these params are invalid?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that this params are invalid because i use it in my other tests.

Comment: i changed to: put :update, id: @car_service, car_addition: attributes_for(:car_service, name: '', type: nil) and now everything is passing. Thank's for help.